# Custom Exception Class - Shall I extend Runtime Exception OR Exception?

Tags: java, android, exception, runtimeexception

**Can any one guide me Shall I extend Exception or RuntimeException?**

Usually, it is used for validations, Unexpected Exceptions, Custom Exception, Raise if Business Logic Fails etc.

Below is my custom exception class.

```
/**
 * The class <code>BaseException</code> is a custom exception class.
 * @author Pratiyush Kumar Singh
 */
public class BaseException  extends Exception {

    static final long serialVersionUID = -3387516993124229948L;

    /**
     * Constructs a new exception.  
     */
    public BaseException() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a new exception with the specified detail message.  
     * @param   message -  It contains the error message.
     */
    public BaseException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a new exception with the specified detail message.  
     * @param   message -  It contains the error message.
     * @param   cause   -  Instance of Throwable.
     */
    public BaseException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some people say that custom exceptions are a code smell.  You certainly shouldn't have too many.

The original default for Java was checked exceptions.  Designers reacted against the C return code convention, because they didn't like the idea that developers could ignore them.  Checked exceptions demand to be caught and handled.

C# went in the other direction and preferred unchecked exceptions.  Littering code with try/catch was found to be cumbersome.

You should decide whether to extend `Exception` (checked) or `RuntimeException` (unchecked) based on your requirements.  Ask yourself: Should I force developers to deal with this situation?

Or you can follow fashion and make them all unchecked.

I recommend that you use existing classes from the JDK as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler does not require clients to handle [RuntimeException](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/RuntimeException.html), whereas it does for `Exception`. Therefore, you should extend from Exception if you want to force clients to write code that attempts to recover from the condition, or from RuntimeException if you don't.

Below is an example of how clients would have to handle if you didn't extend from RuntimeException.

```
void foo() throws MyException(); // throw up the stack

void foo() { // handle exception with try-catch
    try {
    }
    catch (MyException e) {
    }
}
```